# Convert NSTimer to NSUInterval for Array Index

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nstimer

I want to use a NSTimer count to get a corresponding Index position from a sub array.

```
-(void)someMethod: (NSTimer*)t{

 NSUInteger *tickNumber = (NSUInteger)t;
 NSMutableArray *subArray = [dataPoints objectAtIndex:tickNumber];

 //etc...
}
```

I get the warnings:

> "Incompatible integer to point conversion initializing NSUInteger
>   (unsigned long)

How can I use the NSTimer interval to pull out data from a subarray index?

EDIT:
I misunderstood how the properties of the NSTimer worked. I thought that I could more easily access the current interval of the timer. Instead, I now just use my own internal integer in the loop.

```
 NSUInteger frameTicker =0;

-(void)someMethod: (NSTimer*)t{
 frameTicker++;
 NSMutableArray *subArray = [dataPoints objectAtIndex:frameTicker];

 }
```

No conversion is necessary.

Comment: If you cast a pointer (like a timer) you'll get it's address (probably), you won't get the time interval for that timer (that just doesn't make sense because a timer is a lot more than it's time interval). What you can do is to use the `userInfo` property of a timer to store the index and use that when trying to get the array.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez What about timeInterval? 
 NSMutableArray *subArray = [dataPoints objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)t.timeInterval];

Comment: I guess you could use that property of the timer, however the documentation says `If the receiver is a non-repeating timer, returns 0 even if a time interval was set.`, so unless your timer is repeating, it will always return 0. I would suggest you use the `userInfo` property as I mentioned, this kind of situation is what it's there for.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearing that up. See my edits. I was thinking that I could just get the current interval directly from the NSTimer, but it seems like it is more proper to just manage that myself. Does that seem right?

Comment: That's right. I see no advantage to using the time interval because accessing the `userInfo` is the same as accessing the `timeInterval` (except that you have to convert the `NSInteger` into an `NSNumber` and the other way around), however using the `userInfo` makes it more flexible and you can change the time interval if you need without affecting the behaviour of the app. Also keep in mind that `NSTimeInterval` is a `double` so `0.5` casted to `NSUInteger` would be `0`, same with `0.75` and `0.99`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @EmilioPelaez I did not use NSTimer directly:

```
NSUInteger frameTicker =0;
-(void)someMethod: (NSTimer*)t{
 frameTicker++;
 NSMutableArray *subArray = [dataPoints objectAtIndex:frameTicker];

 }
```

I would give him credit, but he did not post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the first warning, we need to know what type is "t" so we can know how to convert it to NSUInteger, the casting is not working.

For avoiding the Second message you should rename your tickNUmber or you can use the property declared with the same name instead of a local variable.

Comment: Thanks, t is a NSTimer. I renamed the var and that took care of that. So, I removed it from the question for clarity. Thanks again

Comment: What about NSMutableArray *subArray = [dataPoints objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)t.timeInterval];